# Asana server returning error code 500 on OAuth 2 request with GTMOAuth 2

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, asana

I'm using the GTMOAuth-2 library to implement an OAuth 2 Authorization Code Grant flow to the Asana API, but consistently getting back a server error 500. The GTMHTTPFetcher log is as follows (selectively redacted):

```
fetch tokens for app.asana.com

2013-05-08 16:46:58 +0000
Request: POST https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_authorize
Request headers:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: gtm-oauth2 <user-agent>

Request body: (199 bytes)
client_id=<client-id>&client_secret=_snip_&code=<client-secret>&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2FOAuthCallback

Response: status 500
Response headers:
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 303
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 08 May 2013 16:46:56 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: <cookie>
X-Asana-Content-String-Length: 303
X-Asana-Preferred-Release-Revision: 20130508_073846_310cafc985fd5fb43121784b58d5dcd2503ffffe

Response body: (303 bytes)
<html>
<head>
<title>Error</title><script>__FILE__="(none)";var config = {
"CLUSTER": "prod",
"PRETTY_JS_CODEGEN": false,
"ENABLED_FEATURES": ""
};</script><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/-/static/luna/browser/images/favicon.ico" />

</head>
<body>
<h3>Error</h3><pre>Server Error</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I've double-checked the auth and token URLs, client ID and secret, made sure the redirect URIs match on Asana and in-app. Interestingly, the authorization flow seems to get as far as authorizing the app (and the Asana site records the app as authorized), but it then never seems to return the authorization token. Is there anywhere I might be going wrong, or is this truly an internal server error?

Comment: (I work at Asana) We never return a 500 on purpose, so there really is a bug. We'll investigateand get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Asana). I'm unsure where in the flow this request is being made, but it doesn't look correct. Once you've obtained the authorization code (by having the user interact with the Asana form), the library should then make a request to our `/-/oauth_token` endpoint, and pass us the code. So it's possible that you just need to be using the `/-/oauth_token` endpoint instead of the `/-/oauth_authorize` endpoint as you're doing.

If you look at our [OAuth examples](https://github.com/Asana/oauth-examples) you'll note that there are two different URLs, one for authorization and one for token exchange.

Asana is probably returning a 500 because it's not expecting this and we're not doing a good enough job catching the problem.

Comment: Thanks Greg - you're a genius (and I, apparently, can't see things even when checking twice). I was using the auth URL for both auth and token requests - changed and works just great. Appreciate you responding.